# Why does running a test in a forked process make Java fail to load a native library?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, java-native-interface

I work on an application that uses a Java library that interfaces with a native library. We're discovering recently that unit tests (using the spring runner) of this code are consistently failing under specific circumstances, but successful in other circumstances.

We use Java 8 and SpringBoot 2.3.12.

I'm currently running these tests on Windows 10.
When I run the tests from "mvn package" without any special qualifications, the tests run successfully.

When I run any of the tests in Eclipse (2022-03), I get `UnsatisfiedLinkError`, and it refers to the first method in a particular class which is defined as "native".  I don't think there's anything special about the class or method, it's likely just the first one that it tries to load.

I also get the exact same error when I add the following properties to my Surefire configuration:

```
                <reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
                <forkCount>1</forkCount>
```

These force each test to run in a separate and new jvm instance.

I also augmented the code that gets run to print out all of the environment variables and system properties.  I stored the results for both the "good" test and the "bad" test into separate files, and I compared them.  There were no significant differences.  Both the java.class.path and java.library.path system property values were identical, along with the PATH environment variable.  The "good" test had a couple of environment variables that indicated the process id.

I tried running SysInternals ProcMon, and I had it filter on the name of the DLL with the native code.  I did this while running both the "good" and "bad" tests.  Both of them appeared to open the correct dll.

I could use some ideas of what else to try here.

If it helps, here is an elided "tail" of the stacktrace (the last "Caused by"). The elided sections are names in our application, which aren't relevant:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com....DIGEST_MD5()I
    at .....DIGEST_MD5(Native Method)
    at .....LibraryContextNative.<clinit>(LibraryContextNative.java:17)
    at .....LibraryContext.getVersion(LibraryContext.java:730)
    at .....getLibraryContext(VoltageHelper.java:142)
    at .....<init>(VoltageHelper.java:99)
    at .....<init>(EncryptorVoltageHelper.java:56)
    at ....getInstance(EncryptorVoltageHelper.java:97)
    at .....getInstance(EncryptorVoltageHelper.java:136)
    at ....<init>(VoltageEncryptFilter.java:72)
    at ...
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331)
    at ...
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:652)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:127)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:275)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:243)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:123)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:244)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:264)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:200)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
```

Comment: Please add the full stack trace of your exception to your question. I suppose that either the PATH environment variable or the `java.library.path` system property are different in the forked process.

Comment: I added an excerpt of the stacktrace, but when I said there were no significant differences in env and sys props, I did mean it. The PATH, java.class.path, and java.library.path were identical.

Comment: In the non-forked case the JVM is getting whatever parameters are in MAVEN_OPTS, which could conceivably have some effect.

Comment: That env var is not set in either the good or bad case.

Comment: Hmm, I think I'm figuring something out here. I need to do more research tomorrow. Basically, I was neglecting the fact that I have to do a "System.load()" of the native library, and that has to be done once per jvm. It was being done in some of the tests, but not all, which is why forking resulted in these failures.